# how to get logged in user data(username) in the models.py file of different app in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

My django project has two apps - home App and models App. Home App is responsible for creating users(signup and login) into database. models App is responsible for predicting heart disease of user and storing disease result. My problem is I want to create a database in models app and want to retrieve the logged in user data in models App database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access the user data using

```
request.user
```

request.user holds the data of the logged user.
if you want every users data, you should probably calls the model and retrieve every users that is

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the models of your home app to model app and use it. something like this

```
 from home.models import User

class Heart(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```